# Is it natural and acceptable to use the phrase 'studies his lessons'?

Tags: grammar

The following sentence is from Grade 6 English Textbook  in Myanmar. In the sentence, is it natural and acceptable to use the phrase 'studies his lessons'?

> He studies his lessons from 8:00 p.m. to 10:00 p.m.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct English, however I would normally say (or hear) "*He studies from 8:00 p.m. to 10:00 p.m.*"

Unless there is a non-school context, studying usually implies studying school work. I'm not sure, but the phrase "studies his lessons" maybe sounds a bit British to me? I'm American.

Comment: I shouldn't blame the British for this expression.

Answer (score 0):

I would understand it, but it is not a fluent English expression.

If "study" has an object, the object is the thing that is studied:

> I studied biology in the morning.
>
> I studied a painting by Da Vinci.

So "He studied his lesson" literally means "He learnt all about the lesson" -- Perhaps he learnt the teacher's name, the start and end times, where all the students sit etc.

It could also mean "Lesson: a passage from the Bible". You could say "The monks studied the lesson from the morning worship".  But that is probably not the meaning here.

We would understand "He had lessons at school from 8-10, and during these lessons he studied". But this is redundant. If you are at school you say "I have classes from 8:00 to 10:00".

But your example has 8-10pm, and most schools are shut at this time.  So perhaps the intended meaning is "He does his homework from 8:00 to 10:00pm"